# Date Picker dialog in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make a Date dialog picker to automaticly fill my EditText.
there are 2 EditText and i don't know how witch editText lanch dialod in my listener.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year= c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day_of_month = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    Log.i(Acceuil.APP_TAG, "DialogFrag method Id: " +this.getId());

    DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), STYLE_NORMAL, (OnDateSetListener)getActivity(), year,month,day_of_month);

    return datePicker;
}
```

And in my activity:

```
 public class AddCar extends FragmentActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener,OnDateSetListener{
    EditText registration_ET=null;
    EditText control_ET=null;
    DialogFragment newFrag= null;
    DialogFragment newFrag2= null;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addcar_layout);
        registration_ET = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.firstRegistration_editText);
        registration_ET.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i(Acceuil.APP_TAG,"Registration ET clicked!");
                newFrag = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFrag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DateRegisterId");
            }
        });
        control_ET = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.control_editText);
        control_ET.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i(Acceuil.APP_TAG,"Registration ET clicked!");
                newFrag2 = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFrag2.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "controlId");
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
        Log.i(Acceuil.APP_TAG, "onDateSet AddCar method");
        //switch (view.getId())
         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
         Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         c.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
         String date = sdf.format(c.getTime());

        }
```

What i want is update the correct editText registration_ET or control_ET depent whitch fragment set the date.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `DatePickerFragment` as following.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day_of_month = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), STYLE_NORMAL, (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), year, month, day_of_month);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setTag(getTag());
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

**Note :**

I have added following two lines to your code.

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), STYLE_NORMAL, (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), year, month, day_of_month);
dialog.getDatePicker().setTag(getTag());
```

Now you can get your tag from `onDateSet` method as following.

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    if (view.getTag().equals("DateRegisterId")) {
        registration_ET.setText(monthOfYear + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year);
    } else if (view.getTag().equals("controlId")) {
        control_ET.setText(monthOfYear + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year);
    }
}
```

**Update**

**1. DatePickerFragment.java**

```
package com.example.androidtester;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day_of_month = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), STYLE_NORMAL, (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), year, month, day_of_month);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setTag(getTag());
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

**2. MainActivity.java**

```
package brightspot.com.androidtester;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private EditText editText;
    private EditText editText2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final DatePickerFragment newFrag = new DatePickerFragment();
        editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                newFrag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "editText");
            }
        });

        editText2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                newFrag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "editText2");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        if (view.getTag().equals("editText")) {
            editText.setText(monthOfYear + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year);
        } else if (view.getTag().equals("editText2")) {
            editText2.setText(monthOfYear + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: setTag is not in DatePickerDialog, which available in [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html), That's why I added `dialog.getDatePicker().setTag(getTag());`.

Comment: I didnt see it.thanks for your help I'm on it since 2 days!

Comment: Now compare the updated code with yours, including `imports`.